# Joint probability distribution table .

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A biased coin has probability $\frac{1}{4}$ of landing on ‘heads’ and $\frac{3}{4}$ of landing on ‘tails’
when tossed. The coin is tossed repeatedly until either two heads or two tails have
been tossed. Let $X$ denote the total number of heads achieved and $Y$ the total number
of tails achieved in the sequence of tosses. Thus, for example, if the first toss is a tail,
and the second and third tosses are both heads then $X = 2$ and $Y = 1$.

(a) Describe the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ by a clearly labelled table.

(b) Find the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$ .

(c) Suppose that $Y = 2$. Find $P(X = x | Y = 2)$ for each possible value of $x$

I have tried to compute the table but I am not getting that the sum of probabilities add up to 1. I am sure I can do the second parts if I get the table right though.

Comment: "until either two heads or two tails have been tossed" you mean consecutive?

Comment: no, they don't have to be consecutive @Tom

Comment: ok - so how many tosses will do you at maximum?

Comment: 3 because on each toss you get either heads or tails so u can either have 2 tosses or 3 tosses until you reach 2 heads or 2 tails

Comment: Perfect - so what is your sample space? What is the probability of each event?

Comment: sample space = {HH, TT, HTH,THT} where H is heads and T is tails and P(H)=1/4 and P(T)=3/4. I have used this for the table but my answers do not add up to 1

Comment: You could use this sample space but you d be more likely to end up in troubles. I suggest you use {HHH, HHT, HTH, HTT, ...}, i.e. {H,T}^3. Then of course X would take the same value on HHH and HHT. Does it help?

Comment: I am just very confused because it says the trials stop after getting 2 heads or 2 tails  so if I have HHT is that correct as it should stop at HH. Is that still the same experiment?

Comment: You could think of it like: if i got HH, i still toss again, but the third toss is completely irrelevant as far as my X and Y are concerned. So for example X(HHT)=2, Y(HHT)=0 and X(HHH)=2, Y(HHH)=0.

Comment: Otherwise you could take as sample space {HH, HTH, HTT, THH, THT, TT} (sorry i misread your comment above where you took {HH, TT, HTH,THT} which would be wrong)

Answer (score 0):

The set of outcomes from this activity are $\{HH, HTH, HTT,TT, THT, THH\}$. The maximum number of coin tosses are three and hence the sample space is

$$\{HHH, HHT, HTH, THH, TTH, THT, HTT, TTT\}$$

From the sample space , you know that $X \in \{0,1,2,3\}$ and $Y \in \{0,1,2,3\}$. We can now derive the joint probabilities. The sum of all values in the table will be $1$.